# UITextView cutting off last line of text

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uitextview

I am trying to render out a `UITextView` within a `UITableViewCell`.

For some reason the last line of my text is being cut off. I have followed numerous posts on here and none of seemed to work.

As you can see the dummy text I have added has additional text now displayed.

```
import UIKit

class CardCell: UITableViewCell {

    private lazy var featureImage: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        return iv
    }()

    private lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .medium)
        l.textColor = .black
        return l
    }()

    private lazy var infoLabel: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView(frame: .zero)
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tv.textContainerInset = .init(top: 0, left: -4, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        tv.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
        tv.textColor = .black
        tv.isEditable = false
        tv.isSelectable = false
        tv.isScrollEnabled = false
        tv.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer consectetur felis ut nulla molestie maximus. Etiam scelerisque nibh tellus, eu hendrerit magna iaculis at."
        tv.sizeToFit()
        return tv
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        backgroundColor = .clear

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: .init(top: 10, left: 12, bottom: 10, right: 12))
    }

    func render(_ model: CellData) {

        featureImage.image = model.featureImage
        titleLabel.text = model.title

        configureConstraints()

    }

    func configureConstraints() {
        [featureImage, titleLabel, infoLabel].forEach { contentView.addSubview($0) }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            featureImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            featureImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            featureImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
            featureImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140),

            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: featureImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),

            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            infoLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
        ])
    }
}
```

[image: cell output]

EDIT

My tableview uses

```
tableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
tableView.allowsSelection = false
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 240
```

Comment: Can you share your `tableview` setup please? Are you setting a fixed size on it and does that size allow for the additional text?

Comment: I have added that now, I am using `automaticDimension`

Comment: if you are using auto dimension then you have to also specify the height  of your text view 

infoLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140)

Comment: ah I see, I assumed it would just resize to fit as I was calling `.sizeToFit()` - I'll try that thank you

Comment: Try remove some insets... I had same problem on xamarin ios, the problem was gone when i removed label padding..

Answer (score 0):

Try this cheating

```
let tv = UITextView(frame: .zero)
tv. ...
tv.text = "Lorem ipsum..."
tv.isScrollEnabled = true
tv.isScrollEnabled = false
return tv
```